# Kill the [help] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Most, if not all, people that use the site need help. So why do we have [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help)?

Let's kill it!

Comment: Go ahead and remove it, it will die naturally when it's not used anymore...

Comment: @YannisRizos In that case, go ahead and stick a [meta-tag:status-completed] on this.

Comment: Oh, great, thanks for doing your part in this. If you notice that the tag re-surfaced, ask for it to be blacklisted (we don't have much chance of that if it doesn't actually come back).

Comment: @YannisRizos No problem. Will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a good tag to just nuke. There are only 16 questions and they all have more relevant tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like mods can just arbitrarily nuke tags. I was actually looking for a way to do just this, since the questions are all tagged with something else.

Comment: @ThomasOwens that is unfortunate, I thought you had that power.